# Java keylistener grid game

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, keylistener

So I am working on a game where an actor is moved by the user in a grid, and if the space the user is trying to move the actor to of a certain type, then it can be moved to. The grid is made up of a class that I know works called PGrid, so the grid is made of PGrids. The problem is the keyListener does not function at all, not even print out 'hi.' Below is the code for PGame and moveGrid, where PGame handles moveGrid stuff but moveGrid draws out the grid (as it is the JPanel). I tried moving the keylistener from PGame to moveGrid, but it did not work.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

//where all the different classes are put together

public class PGame implements KeyListener{ //may want to move the listener to moveGrid
private static moveGrid panel = new moveGrid(8,8); //taking something from moveGrid
private static PActor pguy = new PActor("Bill", 2, 2);
private boolean shallmove = false;
private int newx, newy;

public static void main(String[] args){
    //create a new frame 
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("PGame"); 
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    //moveGrid panel = new moveGrid(8,8); //taking something from moveGrid
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel); 
    frame.pack(); 
    frame.setVisible(true);
    panel.requestFocus();

    //creating a "path" of places able to move to
    moveGrid.pgrids.get(0).changeType(1);
    moveGrid.pgrids.get(1).changeType(1);
    moveGrid.pgrids.get(2).changeType(1);
    moveGrid.pgrids.get(3).changeType(1);
    moveGrid.pgrids.get(10).changeType(1);
    moveGrid.pgrids.get(11).changeType(1);
    moveGrid.pgrids.get(19).changeType(1);
    moveGrid.pgrids.get(27).changeType(1);
    //moveGrid.pgrids.get(4).changeType(2);

    //start our pguy out in a position
    PGrid pguystart = new PGrid(2,0,0);
    moveGrid.pgrids.set(0,pguystart);

    panel.repaint();
}



public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    //here test if the grid can be updated
    //Test:

    pguy.canMove(3,3);
    pguy.Move(4,3,3);

    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        newx = pguy.getx();
        newy = pguy.gety() - 1;
        shallmove = pguy.canMove(newx,newy);
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        newx = pguy.getx();
        newy = pguy.gety() + 1;
        shallmove = pguy.canMove(newx,newy);
    } else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        newx = pguy.getx() - 1;
        newy = pguy.gety();
        shallmove = pguy.canMove(newx,newy);
    }else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        newx = pguy.getx() + 1;
        newy = pguy.gety();
        shallmove = pguy.canMove(newx,newy);
    }


}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { 


    System.out.println("Hi");

    //update the grid if it can here
    //somewhere in here add this:
    //moveGrid.repaint(); //tell movegrid to repaint
    if(shallmove = true){
        //change a certain spot to the actor
        PGrid temp = new PGrid(2,newx,newy);
        moveGrid.pgrids.set(pguy.getplace(),temp);
        //need to also change to old space to be back to what it was....
        //*here*
        pguy.Move(pguy.newPos,newx, newy);
        panel.repaint();
    }


}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }


}
```

moveGrid:

```
//a grid in which stuff can move

import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;

public class moveGrid extends JPanel {
private int height;
private int width;
private int newx, newy;
private static PActor pguy = new PActor("Bill", 2, 2);
private boolean shallmove = false;
public static ArrayList<PGrid> pgrids = new ArrayList<PGrid>(); //an array full of grid boxes with type PGrid

public moveGrid(int height, int width){
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));
    //make all the values in pgrids equal to "Water" and give them locations
    int i = 0;
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){
            PGrid pnull = new PGrid(0, x, y);
            pgrids.add(i, pnull);
            i++;
        }
    }


    //drawGrid();
}

/*public void drawGrid(Graphics g){
    g.drawRect(x,y,20,20);

} */

 public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        requestFocus();
    }

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    //PGrid curLoc = new PGrid(height, height, height);

    //go through and draw out the grid
    int q = 0;
    int midx = 0; //need to make these somehow so the squares get drawn at the center
    int midy = 0;
    for(int qh = 0; qh < height; qh++){
        for(int qw = 0; qw < width; qw++){
            PGrid pcur = pgrids.get(q); //
            int p = pcur.getType();
            if(p == 0){
                //may want to import a water looking image
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g.fillRect((40*qw)+midx,(40*qh)+midy,40,40);
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawRect((40*qw)+midx,(40*qh)+midy,40,40);
            }else if(p == 1){
                //may want to import a better image
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g.fillRect((40*qw)+midx,(40*qh)+midy,40,40);
            }else if(p == 2){
                //draws the "character"
                g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
                g.fillRect((40*qw)+midx,(40*qh)+midy,40,40);
            }
            q++;
        }
    }

    //here draw the character in the proper position
    //so like multiply the x and y by 40 

}
}
```

I also may have an error in the PActor class, which is supposedly the Actor that moves.

```
public class PActor {
private String name;
private int curx, cury;
int newPos;

public PActor(String name, int curx, int cury){
    this.name = name;
    this.curx = curx;
    this.cury = cury;
}

public boolean canMove(int x, int y){
    boolean abletomove = false;
    //test if the space that the user is trying to moveto can be moved to
    //use indexOf(a temp variable with values x and y also with type 1) to test
    PGrid togo = new PGrid(1,x,y);
    //now scan through pgrids in moveGrid to see the desired spot can be moved to
    for(int s = 0; s <= moveGrid.pgrids.size(); s++){
        PGrid temp = moveGrid.pgrids.get(s);
        //test if the temp space is equal
        if((togo.getType() == temp.getType()) && (togo.getx() == temp.getx()) && (togo.gety() == temp.gety())){
            abletomove = true;
            newPos = s;
            break; //stop scanning, as it is now unnecessary
        }
        else{ //do nothing
        }
    }

    //now test pgrids to see if there is a spot like such that is moveable


    return abletomove;
}
public int getplace(){
    return newPos;
}

public int getx(){
    return curx;
}

public int gety(){
    return cury;
}

public void Move(int pos, int x, int y){ 
    PGrid temp = new PGrid(2,x,y);
    moveGrid.pgrids.set(pos,temp);
}

public String toString(){
    return name + " ";
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Again, for any Java Swing listener to work, the listener must be added to a component. For instance for a KeyListener to work, you first need to add it to the component that you wish to have listened to by calling `addKeyListener(myKeyListener)` on that component.
- For a KeyListener to work, the component being listened to must have the keyboard focus. This means that if your'e listening to a JPanel, you first have to make it focusable by calling `setFocusable(true)` on the JPanel and then you need to request focus, such as by calling `requestFocusInWindow()` on it.
- If something later steals the focus, such as a JButton that has been pushed or a text component, then the KeyListener will no longer work.
- To get around this, we usually recommend that you use Key Bindings in place of KeyListeners, but note that the set up of these is completely different from that of KeyListeners, and you would need to throw all assumptions to the side and study the tutorial on use of these first.
- If still stuck, then you will want to create and post a [minimal example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a small program that has a *lot* less code than the program you've posted, yet that compiles for us, runs, and that shows us directly your problem.

Links:

- [KeyListener Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)
- [Key Bindings tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: so i followed all your suggestions and it totally works now. Muchos gracias